# Texture mapping with mayavi and tvkt

Tags: python, 3d, vtk, mayavi

I'm trying to drape a common jpg image over a Mayavi surface with python, inspired by [this example](http://geoexamples.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/3d-terrain-visualization-with-python.html). Here is the simplified code:

```
from mayavi import mlab
from tvtk.api import tvtk
import numpy as np

data=np.random.random((200,200)) #The shape of the matrix fits the image size in the original code
img = tvtk.JPEGReader()
img.file_name="img.jpg"
texture=tvtk.Texture(interpolate=0)   
texture.set_input_data(bmp1.get_output())

mlab.figure(size=(300,300))  
surf = mlab.surf(data,color=(1,1,1)) 
surf.actor.enable_texture = True  
surf.actor.tcoord_generator_mode = 'plane'  
surf.actor.actor.texture = texture
```

However, I'm getting:

```
ERROR: In /tmp/vtk20150328-28275-1clyhqa/VTK-6.2.0/Rendering/OpenGL/vtkOpenGLTexture.cxx, line 200
vtkOpenGLTexture (0x7fa9c32fb590): No scalar values found for texture input!
```

The error is related with the assignation of texture to actor. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There was a Patch in the MayaVI-API, see here:
https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/issues/211

You have to replace:

```
texture=tvtk.Texture(interpolate=0)   
texture.set_input_data(bmp1.get_output())
```

with:

```
texture = tvtk.Texture(input_connection=img.output_port, interpolate=0)
```

Then it should work. Note, that you wrote `bmp1` instead of `img`.

Comment: Want can I do, if I don't have the possibility to update mayavi?

Comment: What is your concrete Problem with updating? If you have admin-rights on your workstation, you could possibly add the patch "by hand"...